# ¿Cómo llenar un tipo de dato creado por el usuario? SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quiero ejecutar un sp que contiene una variable de un tipo de dato que creado.

Pero no sé cómo llenar los datos de la variable @LaTabla que ese de un tipo de dato creado por el usuario. De antemano gracias por su ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para llenar un tipo de dato tabla, debes crear una variable con ese tipo y enviar la variable como argumento.

Dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
DECLARE @Tabla dbo.TipoDatoTabla;

INSERT INTO @Tabla(
    RFC,
    RazonSocial,
    FechaAlta,
    Comentarios,
    Vigente
)
VALUES( 'PISA941215H23', 
        'Ana Pimentel',
        '2022-08-09',
        'Datos de Prueba',
        1),
        ( 'TULA830421H05', 
        'Aldo Tuscano',
        '2022-08-07',
        'Datos de Prueba 2',
        1);

EXEC sp_Cl 
    @Opcion = 3,
    @LaTabla = @Tabla;
```

Comment: Si me funcionó, gracias.